# Material UI (MUI) Autocomplete with initial predefined values

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, autocomplete

I'm trying to create a MUI Autocomplete component that display a sequence from 1 to 50. However, if the user select the component, it should initially only display the numbers 1, 6, 10, 12, 24. If the user type 1 for exemple, it should display all possible matches (1, 11, 21, 31, 41...)

I've tried to do something like this but it didn't work:

```
const [selectedValue, setSelectedValue] = useState("")

const allNumbers = [1, 2, 3, 4 ... 50]
const initialNumbers = [1, 6, 10, 12, 24]

const actionOnChange = (e) => {
    setSelectedValue(e.target.value)
}

<Autocomplete
    id={id}
    options={selectedValue ? optionsData : optionsFiltered}
    onChange={e => actionOnChange(e)}
    value={selectedValue}
```

Comment: think u are missing renderInput prop which is necessary

Comment: and  double check that `e.target.value` have the value you want, not sure if autocomplete return like this  I had this in onChange `onChange={(e: never, newValue) =>{})`

Answer (score 0):

Please try changing actionOnChange to this.

```
    const actionOnChange = (e) => {
    const newArr = allNumbers.filter((item) => item.toString().startsWith(e.target.value.toString()))
    setSelectedValue(newArr);
}
```